# Upload xlsx file with Cypress using cypress-file-upload

Tags: file, encoding, cypress

I'm using cypress-file-upload in order to upload an xlsx file into a form.

I've tried 2 solutions.

```
// First one
cy.fixture(fileName).then((fileContent) => {
    cy.get("input[type='file']").attachFile({
        fileContent,
        fileName,
        encoding : 'UTF-8',
        mimeType : 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    })
})

// Second one
cy.get("input[type='file']").attachFile({
    filePath : "file/path",
    encoding : 'utf-8',
    mimeType : 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
})
```

With both solutions, the file is uploaded with no Cypress error, but the form rejects the file with a generic error message.

Any idea? I bet there's something about encoding but I can't find what... Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with the code below. [Reference](https://github.com/abramenal/cypress-file-upload#waiting-for-the-upload-to-complete)

Edited:

```
const fileName = 'upload_1.xlsx';

cy.fixture(fileName, 'binary')
    .then(Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob)
    .then(fileContent => {
        cy.get("input[type='file']").attachFile({ fileContent, fileName, mimeType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', encoding:'utf8' })
    })
```

Comment: Mmmh... Tried it and got the following error: `TypeError: cy.get(...).upload is not a function`

Comment: Worked like a charm when I replaced `upload` by `attachFile` ;) Thank you, I accept your answer!!